Decay Rates of Harmonics in Standing Waves on a String
In my class experiment on standing waves on a string, I used the FFT mode of an oscilloscope to analyze the frequencies produced by the string. I observed that the fundamental frequency exhibited the slowest decay rate, which makes sense due to its simple mode shape with fewer nodes.
However, I was surprised to find that the highest harmonic (the largest possible frequency) also had a relatively slow decay rate, coming in second after the fundamental frequency. I understand that the fundamental frequency has less energy loss due to fewer nodes and a more stable configuration.
I wonder if the slower decay rate of the highest harmonic could be related to how the FFT mode works in analyzing the signal. Are there specific factors related to boundary conditions, energy distribution, or material properties that might contribute to this observation?
Here's some more information. The diameter of the string is $0.371 mm$, and its line density is $1.01\times10^{-3}kg/m$. I repeated the experiment three times, using string lengths of $100 mm$, $200 mm$, and $300 mm$, and I observed this phenomenon consistently, with the most significant effect at the $100 mm$ length. I have included an image of the decay for the $300 mm$ string length (unfortunately, I didn't take a photo for the $100 mm$ length).
The string is mounted on an instrument specifically designed for this experiment. I’ve drawn a diagram to help explain the setup. It might look complicated, but imagine it like this: you have a metal string (similar to a rubber band) with its two ends fixed to a table. Two rulers (acting as barricades) hold up the string in place.
I excited the string at various random locations, but I didn’t notice any significant difference in the results based on where the excitation occurred. I’ve also added another picture of the string when the length was set to $300 mm$. In this image, you can clearly see the peaks in the power spectrum. The frequency data is in the table, but unfortunately, I only took that one set of data.
Regarding the small peaks in the decay, those represent $2f$ and possibly $14f$.



(n)
1
2
3
4
(\dots)
14




(f/\text{Hz})
340
680
1040
1380
(\dots)
4660







We're going to need to see some data. Maybe an initial and then delayed PSD? Also how thick/long is the string? The finite thickness should push the resonant frequencies above the integer harmonics.

Thank you for your attention! I have added some additional information and an image to my post; hopefully, it will help clarify my observations.

Your question needs to give more information about the setup. Is the string part of a musical instrument with a wooden body or ist the string simply held between massive metal clamps in air? How do you excite the string at which location, in the middle, at the end? Have zou checked whether this would make a difference in the effect?

I'm with @freecharly on this. The scope-trace (yellow) is very sine-like. I was expecting to see clear $1f, 2f, 3f, 4f, 5f, \cdots$ peaks in the power spectrum. The fundamental is clear...if that small peak to its near right is the 1st harmonic at $2f$ then the peak to the far right, (idk $8f$ or more?) looks like some kind of aliasing (though that usually maps higher freq. to lower ones). We'd need to know more about the setup, and some numbers for where those peaks are. It's not like any PSD I've seen before.

@freecharly any stringed instrument with a PSD like that would get the luthier kicked out of the guild!

What is "the largest possible frequency"? What is its value, and why? The only limit on frequency that comes to mind is that on wavelength due to inter-atomic spacing, and contribution to the spectrum at such high frequency is very hard to measure.

@JEB, thank you for your insights! I’ve added more detailed information about the setup along with some additional data. The instrument might seem a bit complex, but feel free to ask if anything is unclear—I’m happy to provide more details or clarifications!

@freecharly, thank you for your thoughts! I’ve added more information about the setup and some detailed data. The instrument might seem a little complicated, but feel free to ask if anything is unclear—I’m happy to provide more details!

@Ján Lalinský, by "the largest possible frequency," I mean the highest frequency peak I could observe on the oscilloscope. I’m not entirely sure why there aren't higher frequencies visible—I suspect it might be due to the limitations of the oscilloscope (I tried to capture more, but it indicated it had reached its limit). I've added some additional data, including the value of the highest harmonic.

@shotbetter All damping mechanisms of a string itself,  like air or inner friction seem to increase with increasing frequency. Therefore, other mechanisms (e.g, decreased coupling to the mount or table)  have to be considered for the lower damping of the vibration at higher frequency.

@freecharly, thank you for your thoughts! I’ve developed a theory suggesting that the oscilloscope might "fold" frequencies above its limit into the highest harmonic, which could explain why the highest harmonic decays more slowly. To test this theory, I plan to redo the experiment with a better oscilloscope. However, I’m currently focused on some exams, so I’ll aim to conduct the experiment sometime next week.

@shotbetter Sounds interesting! I wish you good luck!

Thank you @JEB for your insights! I’ve posted an answer with the results of further experiments and the explanation—your feedback helped me a lot!

Thank you @freecharly for your insights! I’ve posted an answer with the results of further experiments and the explanation—your feedback helped me a lot!

Thank you @Ján Lalinský for your insights! I’ve posted an answer with the results of further experiments and the explanation—your feedback helped me a lot!

After conducting further research and another experiment, I believe the unusual phenomenon I observed is due to aliasing.
In my initial experiment, I used an older RIGOL DS1102E oscilloscope, which has a limited measurement bandwidth. This bandwidth wasn’t large enough to capture the full frequency range accurately, leading to aliasing. Essentially, aliasing occurs when the sampling frequency of the oscilloscope  ($f_s$)is too low to capture the full detail of a signal. This results in a mirrored or "folded" frequency spectrum between 0 and $f_s$, creating what is known as a "ghost peak." In my case, the highest harmonic was actually an aliased version of the fundamental frequency. For more information on aliasing, you can refer to this Wikipedia article: Aliasing on Sampling Sinusoidal Functions. Figures 2 and 4 in the article show a very similar phenomenon to what I observed.
To test this hypothesis, I performed another experiment. Although I couldn’t find the original string from the previous experiment, I was able to replicate the effect using a different string, as shown in the first image.  You can see that the highest harmonic, in this case at
2.330kHz, has a significant peak. However, when I used a better oscilloscope (RIGOL MSO1104Z), that peak disappeared. In the second image, you can see when I set the central frequency to 2.330kHz, and there’s no peak at all—not even a ripple. 
Thank you to @JEB, @freecharly, and @Ján Lalinský for their insightful comments—this discovery wouldn’t have been possible without your help!
